# Stacked and beside bar plot with percentage on y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe in R with ~7000 rows. 10 rows of my data frame are shown-

```
TypeA   TypeB   Ct_for_typeA    Ct_for_typeB
code3   code2   m               n
code4   code1   m               p
code3   code7   p               n
code8   code6   n               n
code1   code3   m               p
code5   code8   n               o
code2   code1   o               p
code5   code5   p               m
code7   code4   o               m
code6   code1   m               o
```

Column 1 (TypeA) and Column 2 (TypeB) have 8 different codes from code1 to code8. Column 3 and Column 4 have 4 different categories i.e. m, n, o and p. I want to plot a bar plot with code1 to code8 on x axis and "percentage" on y-axis. It means x-axis will have 8 pairs of bars and y-axis will show the percentage of codes and further I want to divide each bar with different color stacks according to Column 3 (for Column 1) and Column 4 (for Column 2). Example:

Considering only 1st pair of code on x-axis i.e. code1. From above 10 rows, we can see code1 in "TypeA" is 10% and in "TypeB" it is 30%. So first pair has first bar till 10% and second bar till 30%. Now first bar of first pair will be divided (stacked colors) according to 3rd Column. As we can see there is only "m" with code1, the color will be of "m" (whole 10%) but for code1 in "TypeB" i.e. second bar of first pair will be divided into 20% with color "p" and 10% with color "o".

I have tried stacking the colors with "beside=F" and it is working. It means if I have only 1st and 3rd column, I can do it easily. But including second bar for 2nd and 4th column is confusing me.
I hope my explanation is not confusing. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: After the comment by Thomas.

If "my_frame" is the dataframe with above 10 rows. For single variable with stacked colors I used-

```
px=ggplot(my_frame,aes(x=TypeA,fill=Ct_for_typeA))+geom_bar()
print(px)
```

So first of all, here I am not getting the percentage on y-axis and secondly how can I put "beside" bar which is in 2nd column and stacked colors are in 4th column.

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, it was easy for me to make barplot with 1st and 3rd column but with additional columns I did not find any thing on the internet which leads me further.

Comment: So show us the code you've used so far so people don't have to do all the work again to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you showed a wide format of your data. This means each variable is one column. ggplot rather likes a long format.

For counting in the data frame you can use the `data.table` package. Since your names aka codes are called the same you cannot easily use the `melt` function from the reshape2 package. Hence the detour via the `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
test.df <- read.table("your.data", header=T, sep='\t')

# create a data table
test.dt <- as.data.table(test.df)

# here it would be possible to use melt, if your "codes" wouldn't be named identical

# count TypeA
 test.a.count.dt <- test.dt[, length(Ct_for_typeA), by="TypeA" ]
 test.a.count.dt
    TypeA V1
1: code1  1
2: code2  1
3: code3  2
4: code4  1
5: code5  2
6: code6  1
7: code7  1
8: code8  1

# do the same for TypeB
test.b.count.dt <- test.dt[, length(Ct_for_typeB), by="TypeB" ]

colnames(test.a.count.dt) <- c("code","count")
colnames(test.b.count.dt) <- c("code","count")

test.a.count.dt$type <- "TypeA"
test.b.count.dt$type <- "TypeB"


# fuse the two data sets
# this is a long data format that suits ggplot better
test.all.count.dt <- rbind(test.a.count.dt, test.b.count.dt)

colnames(test.all.count.dt) <- c("code","count","type")

# this can be plotted already, but it isn't relative
ggplot(data=test.all.count.dt, aes(code, count, fill=type)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")

# the detour to get relative counts
test.all.count.dt$relative <- apply(test.all.count.dt, 1, function(x){
 count<-x[2];
 type<-x[3];
 return(as.numeric(count)/sum(test.all.count.dt$type==type))
})

# finally plot your relative counts
ggplot(data=test.all.count.dt, aes(code, relative, fill=type)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

ggplot's `geom_bar` already features a `stat=count` method, but this only plots absolute data. I couldn't find a way to directly make `geom_bar` return relative values.